# how to parse pdf file in java and save some data in mysql database

Tags: java, itext

I want to parse a `pdf` file in java and extract some transactional data from it. I have used `iText` to read pdf. It returns whole pdf as a string. I am not able to extract data. What is the better approach to handle this?

Below are the content which i get after parsing my pdf file which is in string format and i need to filter the transactional data so that i can insert it into database.

Date Transaction Amount Units Price                     Unit
(INR) (INR) Balance
Birla Sun Li[e Mutual Fund
Folio No: 1016409683 PAN: AZMPB2802L KYC: OK  PAN: OK
B291GZ-Birla Sun Life India GenNext Fund - Growth-Direct Plan(Advisor: DIRECT) Registrar : CAMS
 Opening Unit Balance: 0.000
12-Mar-2014 Purchase 5,000.00 146.113 34.22 146.113
22-Apr-2014 Purchase - via Internet 1,500.00 41.993 35.72 188.106
05-May-2014 Purchase - via Internet 1,500.00 42.505 35.29 230.611
13-Jan-2015 Purchase - via Internet 1,500.00 28.604 52.44 259.215
3-Feb-2015 Purchase - via Internet 3,000.00 54.835 54.71 314.050
03-Mar-2015 Purchase - via Internet 3,000.00 53.476 56.10 367.5260

Valuation on 10-Mar-2016: INR 58,956.90
Closing Unit Balance: 1,143.462 NAV on 10-Mar-2016: INR 51.56

Comment: What did you try? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need human intelligence if you want to parse a PDF that isn't tagged to a format that is structured (e.g. XML). The core iText library is too limited for that purpose. However, you can write your own add-on to achieve what you need (that will cost you several months of development), or you can buy an iText add-on that is capable of doing this: watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdahNtOFBLo) about the [pdf2Data](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdf2Data) add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific situation you're in, you can try various approaches.

- iText has a tool called pdf2Data, which sounds like it does exactly what you're looking for. It processes a document according to a template, and gives you an xml document. This is of course more suited for a commercial setting.
- You can write your own extraction strategy, that handles the pdf document in a more clever way. Suppose for instance that you want to extract information from a table in a pdf document.

  You would implement IEventListener, and listen for two kinds of events; line-drawing events (so that you get notified when the table is being drawn) and text-rendering events (to get the content in the table).

  You then have to write several smart heuristics that define what constitutes a table. For a simple proof-of-concept you could simply look for lines that cross in 90 degree angles. Determine the bounding box. Then go looking for all text-rendering instructions within that box. Use another clever heuristic that is able to determine column and row-boundaries.

Comment: Please check the above question, i have edit it and add the data which i need to parse

Comment: Could you also provide the original pdf document? (Or a link to it?)

Comment: iText converts this pdf in string which is not formatted.

Comment: That makes perfect sense though.
Would you expect iText to start drawing tables using ASCII-art?
You're going from a rich and structured format to basically a String. You can't complain about loss of structure if your conversion is going to do this by design.

Comment: No, what i mean to say is text are not in order as it appears in pdf. In between few texts are out of order. Manipulating a string which is unexpected in between is difficult. So i am not able find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need actually, IS a String and the procedure you're looking for is called parsing. Once you get that String containing the whole pdf, you need to write some "smart" (saying smart as it depends on the contents of your pdf) code that can split the main String into smaller, more useful (for you) parts.

After that, you need to setup a connection with a database with your java app and provide the necessary db code that will use the smaller String parts you created with your parser to fill up your tables.

Bellow, you can see some code i've written for an assignment which required parsing useful parts of a larger String object from a stream (in this case a .txt containing stats from a basketball game).

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parse (InputStream input) throws IOException {

        output = new ArrayList();
        count = 0;
        atcount = 0;

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
            if (input != null) {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                        
                    if (line.contains("Team")) {
                        playerBounds = false;
                        team2Bounds = true;
                        count = 0;
                    }   

                    if (playerBounds == true && team2Bounds == false) {                             
                        count++;
                        listΑ = line.split("\t");

                        addToList();
                        //printAll();
                    }

                    if ((playerBounds == true) && (team2Bounds == true)) {  
                        count++;
                        listΑ = line.split("\t");

                        addToList();
                        //printAll();
                    }

                    if (line.contains("Player")) {                                  
                        playerBounds = true;
                    }
                    atcount = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

I hope this can help you :)

Comment: Please check the above question, i have edit it and add the data which i need to parse

Comment: Please read Joris' answer and my content. It appears to me that you ignored what Joris was telling you. (Or maybe you didn't fully understand.)